# MapReduce Job Failing with -- Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a simple count program on Hadoop. My input file is of size 4 GB. For some reason the job keeps failing with the errors:

[image]

[image]

However if I try the same code with a small input file say 100MB , it works perfectly fine. I am new at this and I can't seem to find any viable solution. My set up is Psuedo Distributed.

Do I need to make any configuration changes? I have made the standard configurations for the Psuedo distributed set up as provided by the hadoop documentation.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Error Stacktrace you have posted, the ConnectionRefused exception is for JobHistoryServer.

For Pseudo Distributed setup, no configurational changes are required to start the `JobHistoryServer`. Use this command to start it,

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. I am still not sure why this was required or the MapReduce program to run. Is it because the size of the file is too big? @franklinsijo could you please just clarify that or point me to the direction where this information is available.

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava Typical MR jobs can run without having the `JHS`. It is strange why it is needed in your case when the data volume is huge. I have ran jobs on much larger volume without JHS. It is actually the Job client trying to access the AM to gain the status of the job, if the job is completed AM will redirect the incoming request to JHS. If JHS is not running, this exception is thrown. Very commonly seen in `Pig`. Did you use any custom JobClient to submit the job?

Comment: Ohh yea I saw most of the explanations for this problem were related to Pig.   It is strange , I thought it was perhaps because of the size of the input, thank you for your explanation.And no, I did not use any custom JobClient.

Comment: What distribution and Version of Hadoop is it?

Comment: Hadoop version 2.7.3, Psuedo distributed